# Is it possible to run OSB without Weblogic Server?

Tags: weblogic, osb

I just would like to know whether it is possible to run OSB services without weblogic server?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No

Long answer: Anything is possible, but it would involve a *lot* of time getting it to work, and since the OSB license includes WLS, why bother?